# p:multiSelectListbox with Ajax

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, nullpointerexception, multi-select

How can I use `p:multiSelectListbox` with ajax event? I would like enabled button when user chose some option.

```
<p:multiSelectListbox value="#{assignLecturerBacking.lecturerToAssignId}" effect="slide">  
    <f:selectItems value="#{assignLecturerBacking.lecturerList}"/>  
    <f:ajax event="click" render="bt"/>
</p:multiSelectListbox>  

<h:commandButton id="bt" value="#{msg.assignLecturer}" action="#assignLecturerBacking.assignLecturer(true)}"/>
```

I try `f:ajax` with `event=click` or `event=valueChanged` but i get some exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.jsf.core.AjaxHandler.applyAttachedObject(AjaxHandler.java:351)
org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.jsf.core.AjaxHandler.apply(AjaxHandler.java:228)
javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:49)
javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:58)
org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.java:294)
....
```

with `<p:ajax event="change" update="bt"/>` i get `java.lang.NullPointerException` too:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
org.primefaces.component.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorHandler.applyAttachedObject(AjaxBehaviorHandler.java:178)
org.primefaces.component.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorHandler.apply(AjaxBehaviorHandler.java:157)
javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:49)
javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:58)
org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.java:294)
javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:53)
javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:49)
javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:58)
org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.java:294)
javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:53)
javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:49)
....
```

Comment: Can you show the view code?

Comment: I didn't find any available events for the component `p:multiSelectListbox`...

Comment: so what can I do to disabled button when i don't have choose any option and enabled it on chose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `p:multiSelectListbox` component doesn't have any AJAX event available in the PrimeFaces 4.0 version (I suppose they will add some in the future).

One available alternative is to use plain JavaScript/jQuery to get the functionnality you want.

Here is a plain working example I just made to show you how it could be done.

**View code :**

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:multiSelectListbox id="selector" value="#{multiSelectListboxBean.selection}" effect="slide">
        <f:selectItems value="#{multiSelectListboxBean.categories}" />
    </p:multiSelectListbox>

    <h:commandButton id="button" value="Submit" disabled="true" />
    <script>
        $(document).ready(
            function()
            {
                $("#form\\:selector li").click(
                    function()
                    {
                        var data = $(this).attr("data-value");
                        if(data.length > 0)
                        {
                            $("#form\\:button").prop("disabled",false);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $("#form\\:button").prop("disabled",true);
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    </script>
</h:form>
```

**Bean code :**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MultiSelectListboxBean
{
    private List<SelectItem> categories;  

    private String selection;  

    @PostConstruct  
    public void init()
    {
        categories = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        SelectItemGroup group1 = new SelectItemGroup("Group 1");
        SelectItemGroup group2 = new SelectItemGroup("Group 2");
        SelectItemGroup group3 = new SelectItemGroup("Group 3");
        SelectItemGroup group4 = new SelectItemGroup("Group 4");

        SelectItemGroup group11 = new SelectItemGroup("Group 1.1");
        SelectItemGroup group12 = new SelectItemGroup("Group 1.2");

        SelectItemGroup group21 = new SelectItemGroup("Group 2.1");

        SelectItem option31 = new SelectItem("Option 3.1", "Option 3.1");
        SelectItem option32 = new SelectItem("Option 3.2", "Option 3.2");
        SelectItem option33 = new SelectItem("Option 3.3", "Option 3.3");
        SelectItem option34 = new SelectItem("Option 3.4", "Option 3.4");

        SelectItem option41 = new SelectItem("Option 4.1", "Option 4.1");

        SelectItem option111 = new SelectItem("Option 1.1.1");
        SelectItem option112 = new SelectItem("Option 1.1.2");
        group11.setSelectItems(new SelectItem[]{option111, option112});

        SelectItem option121 = new SelectItem("Option 1.2.1", "Option 1.2.1");
        SelectItem option122 = new SelectItem("Option 1.2.2", "Option 1.2.2");
        SelectItem option123 = new SelectItem("Option 1.2.3", "Option 1.2.3");
        group12.setSelectItems(new SelectItem[]{option121, option122, option123});

        SelectItem option211 = new SelectItem("Option 2.1.1", "Option 2.1.1");
        group21.setSelectItems(new SelectItem[]{option211});

        group1.setSelectItems(new SelectItem[]{group11, group12});
        group2.setSelectItems(new SelectItem[]{group21});
        group3.setSelectItems(new SelectItem[]{option31, option32, option33, option34});
        group4.setSelectItems(new SelectItem[]{option41});

        categories.add(group1);
        categories.add(group2);
        categories.add(group3);
        categories.add(group4);
    }

    public List<SelectItem> getCategories()
    {
        return categories;
    }

    public String getSelection()
    {
        return selection;
    }

    public void setSelection(String selection)
    {
        this.selection = selection;
    }
}
```

You will be able to easily adapt this solution to your code. I also made sure that when you click on item groups this wont enable the button.